# Redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable'

Tags: c

Alright, I'm about to lose my mind. I'm supposed to write a program for class that determines the number of the day of the year you input (accounting for leap years), and I feel like I have no idea what I'm doing. I would appreciate any help that I can get before my stress level goes up even more. The final errors I'm getting before even being able to test my program (which I doubt will work) are:

```
error C2365: 'leap' : redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable'
```

and

```
error C2365: 'count' : redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable'
```

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int d, m, y, x, day, leap, count;


    //Input values for date
    printf("\n Input the Day: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &d);

    printf("\n Input the Month: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &m);

    printf("\n Input the Year: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &y);
    //End input

    int count(int m, int day);

    int leap(int y, int x);



    if (x == 1){
            printf("\nThe day of the year is %f", day + 1);
    }
    else{
            printf("\nThe day of the year is %f", day);
    }

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}


//Count the number of days
int count(int m, int day, int d){
    if (m == 1){
        day = d;
    }
    if (m == 2){
        day = 31 + d;
    }
    if (m == 3){
        day = 59 + d;
    }
    if (m == 4){
        day = 90 + d;
    }
    if (m == 5){
        day = 120 + d;
    }
    if (m == 6){
        day = 151 + d;
    }
    if (m == 7){
        day = 181 + d;
    }
    if (m == 8){
        day = 212 + d;
    }
    if (m == 9){
        day = 243 + d;
    }
    if (m == 10){
        day = 273 + d;
    }
    if (m == 11){
        day = 304 + d;
    }
    if (m == 12){
        day = 334 + d;
    }
    return(day);
}

//Determine if it's a leap year
int leap(int y, int x){
    if (y % 400 == 0){
        x = 1;
    }
    else if (y % 100 == 0){
        x = 0;
    }
    else if (y % 4 == 0){
        x = 1;
    }
    else{
        x = 0;
    }
    return(x);
}
```

Comment: Those are not function calls in your main function, you're *declaring functions*. You need to follow the syntax of tutorials more closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The followings are the function declarations, which are not allowed in `main()` (local function definitions are illegal). You should put them before `main()`.

```
int count(int m, int day);
int leap(int y, int x);
```

In addition, based your definition, the function declaration of `count()` should be:

```
int count(int m, int day, int d);
```

And remove `int leap, count;`, which is declaration for data type (`int` here) not for functions.

If you want to call them in `main()`, just use:

```
count(m, day, d);
leap(y, x);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to declare you functions `leap` and `count` like data type.

```
int d, m, y, x, day, leap, count;
```

Remove `leap` and `count` as below

```
int d, m, y, x, day;
```

Below are your function prototype and that is correct (and enough for compiler)

```
int count(int m, int day);

int leap(int y, int x);
```

Answer (score 0):

`count` and `leap` are same variable and function name in your `main` it's not valid.